# KML <IconStyle> Tag is not working in google map

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have a KMl file with some multigeometries. When I import this KML file in Google Earth it looks like this image.

[image]

But when I Import same KML in Google Map is shows Like This

[image]

In Place of Lable it shows default blue color icon.

this is My Sample KMl for One Multigeomety

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Style id="Yellow"><IconStyle><scale>0</scale></IconStyle><PolyStyle><color>6414F0FF</color></PolyStyle></Style><Placemark><styleUrl>#Yellow</styleUrl><name>0,15</name><MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-97.04983000000001,32.81053</coordinates></Point><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-97.05083000000002,32.81083 -97.04667,32.81083 -97.04667,32.8075 -97.05083000000002,32.8075 -97.05083000000002,32.81083</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry></Placemark></Document></kml>
```

I have already googled so many time, Please help on this.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps has issues with [MultiGeometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#multigeometry) placemarks.

If want label from the point and use Polygon then best to have separate placemark for Point with LabelStyle/IconStyle and another for the Polygon. Google Earth has no such issue with MultiGeometry features.

UPDATE:
Using Google Maps KmlLayer does not allow the label names to appear on the map - label only appears when click on placemark icon. If you want to stay with Google Maps then you might try geoxml3 library to parse the KML then enumerate the placemark and create [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels) using Google Maps API. Alternately, can use [Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html?q=kml) or [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/for-google-earth-developers.html) to parse KML and display correctly.

Comment: But in google map , It shows placemark name when we click on the marker, Not like google earth.Please see google earth image ,

Comment: In attached google earth image , I have shown some text like (3,42) (2,42)
as placemark name , All text are showing correctly in google earth, But in google map it shows as popup and on Load, google map shows only default marker in place of these names.

Comment: If Google Maps ignores the IconStyle scale try adding empty href tag in it `<IconStyle> <scale>0</scale> <Icon> <href/> </Icon> </IconStyle>`

Comment: It is not working, Google map shows blue color default marker.

Comment: Google Maps API and KmlLayer is ignoring the iconStyle and name label appearing on its map. It's a bug or undocumented feature. Have you tried using [openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html?q=kml), [cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/for-google-earth-developers.html), or geoxml3 to load the KML file?